# Node Js Debug - 1337 port not monitored

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-debugging

I've installed the latest NodeJs and NodeJs tools for Vs2013.  (**Both Visual Studio 2013 and Node Js were run in Administrative Mode**)
I created a simple Node Js Web project in vs 2013.  The code is given below:

```
var http = require('http');
var port = 1337;
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(port);
```

When I press CTRL + F5 to launch the web node app.  **It worked perfectly.**  The browser can be launched automatically with "hello, world" displayed.

When I press F5, a console window poped up and showing "`debugger listening on port 5858`"
However, there's **no browser pop up after that**.  And **port 1337 is NOT listened** when I try to access it through http:// localhost:1337 /

Is there anything I need to check? Seems there's something wrong with the debugger.  And there's no windows event log about this.

Really appreciate if some one could provide some idea.

Comment: What is `process.env.port` when you use F5?